# Помогите пожалуйста реализовать идею на Python

Tags: python

Только начал интересоваться программированием, очень интересует как реализовать данную задумку на Python.

Суть:
Есть определенная игра, я хочу автоматизировать в ней некие процессы, а именно:
Тут приведен пример интерфейса игры
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKOyw.png)

Слева внизу мини карта, на ней изображен желтый объект и иконка персонажа на нем, это значит что персонаж стоит на этом объекте.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при смене цвета объекта ( с желтого на зеленый ) , данная программа нажимала кнопку на клавиатуре и кликала в 2 разных места на экране ( а именно по кнопкам "ОК" )

Я реализовал это в программе Clickermann

Код выглядит так:

```html
GETSCREEN(160,997,181,1015)
COLORMODE (6)
IF_PIXEL_IN (160,997,181,1015,8388479)  // Зеленый
   KEYPRESS(#E)
   KEYUP(#E)
   WAITMS(100)
   LCLICK(955,600)
   WAITMS(100)
   LCLICK(955,600)
   WAITMS(100)
   LCLICK(955,600)
   WAITMS(100)
   LCLICK(955,600)
END_IF
```

Этот код делает следующее:

1. GETSCREEN(160,997,181,1015) - Делает скриншот заданной бласти на экране
2. COLORMODE (6) - Процедура изменяет текущий снимок экрана, применяя к нему фильтр, снижающий количество цветов в палитре ( 6 = 64 цвета )
3. IF_PIXEL_IN (160,997,181,1015,8388479) - Данная строка сканирует определенную область "160,997,181,1015" на наличие пикселя с цветом "8388479"
4. Если в описанной области был найден пиксель с нужным цветом то команда KEYPRESS(#W) и KEYUP(#W) Нажимает и отжимает кнопку "W"

5)WAITMS(100) - ожидание 100 мс

6)LCLICK(955,600) - клик мышкой в определенное место на экране, где "955,600" - это координаты клика

7. WAITMS(100) - ожидание 100 мс
8. LCLICK(955,600) - клик мышкой в определенное место на экране, где "955,600" - это координаты клика

В кликерманне это все вроде как хорошо работает, вот хотелось бы написать собственную программу именно с таким функционалом

Так же в кликермане запуск данного кода стартует при нажатии определенного сочетания клавиш
Хотелось бы это реализовать в своей программе тоже

Кто может помочь подсказать , буду безмерно благодарен <3

Comment: Вам нужен сеанс менторства по изучению Python, а не ответ на вопрос, заданный по правилам сообщества. Либо это заказ на фриланс, условно говоря. В любом случае SO - это не тот ресурс! Начните изучение Python и вообще программирования с чего-нибудь более простого?

Comment: Дело в том что для заказов на фриланс мне еще очень далеко) я только начинаю изучать программирование) вроде бы реализовать данную программу не особо сложно, вот хотелось бы понять либо как либо с чего начать изучение чтобы реализовать ее самому)

Comment: В кликермане-то? На мой взгляд, это довольно сложная программа сама по себе и она прячет 90% сложности. Повторюсь, что это не тот ресурс, где начинающий сможет определиться какие первые шаги ему делать. Конкретные трудности - велкам, но вот так... Сомневаюсь. Пусть более опытные товарищи из сообщества меня поправят. Гораздо больше помогут поисковые системы и их ответы на "Изучение Python первые шаги", а потом "Библиотека для разработки графических приложений Python", или "Как писать игры на Python" - разве так сложно?

Comment: так вот и прошу направить в нужное русло :-)

Comment: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ вот эта либа поможет нажать клавиши и даже скриншот сделать, удачи)